# Storing properties within database using Commons Configuration

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, apache-commons-config

I want to store some properties in a database table. I'm using **Apache Commons Configuration 2.1**. I found [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/DatabaseConfiguration.html), but I can't make it to work...

I've googled around, but I haven't found any documentation or examples but the link I've written above.

(Edit: code is now fixed)

This is the database structure (postgresql):

```
-- Table: public.propcalendars

-- DROP TABLE public.propcalendars;

CREATE TABLE public.propcalendars
(
  name character varying NOT NULL,
  key character varying NOT NULL,
  value character varying,
  CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (name, key)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.propcalendars
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

And the following data is stored:

```
name            key     value
diasemana       SV2     0000010
fechafinal      SV2     31/08
fechainicial    SV2     01/07
```

This is my code:

```
public class PropertiesConfiguration {

    /*
     * Atributos
     */
    private static PropertiesConfiguration INSTANCE = null;

    private DatabaseConfiguration configFechaInicioAnual;
    private DatabaseConfiguration configFechaFinAnual;
    private DatabaseConfiguration configDiasSemana;

    /*
     * Métodos
     */
    private PropertiesConfiguration() throws ConfigurationException {
        configure();
    }

    private void configure() throws ConfigurationException {

        PGSimpleDataSource postgres = new PGSimpleDataSource();
        postgres.setServerName("ip");
        postgres.setDatabaseName("database");
        postgres.setPortNumber(5433);
        postgres.setUser("user");
        postgres.setPassword("***");
        postgres.setCurrentSchema("public");

        BasicConfigurationBuilder<DatabaseConfiguration> builder = new BasicConfigurationBuilder<DatabaseConfiguration>(DatabaseConfiguration.class);
        builder.configure(
            new Parameters()
            .database()
            .setDataSource(postgres)
            .setTable("propcalendars")
            .setKeyColumn("key")
            .setValueColumn("value")
            .setConfigurationNameColumn("name")
            .setConfigurationName("fechainicial")
        );

        configFechaInicioAnual = new DatabaseConfiguration();
        configFechaInicioAnual.setDataSource(postgres);
        configFechaInicioAnual.setKeyColumn("key");
        configFechaInicioAnual.setValueColumn("value");
        configFechaInicioAnual.setConfigurationName("fechainicial");

    }

    public static PropertiesConfiguration getInstance() throws ConfigurationException{
        if(INSTANCE == null){
            INSTANCE = new PropertiesConfiguration();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public DatosCalendario getInfoCalendario(String pClaveCalendario, String pInfoCalendario){
        DatosCalendario dc = new DatosCalendario();
        dc.descripcion  = pInfoCalendario;
        dc.inicio       = configFechaInicioAnual.getString(pClaveCalendario);
        dc.fin          = "";//configFechaInicioAnual.getString(pClaveCalendario);
        dc.diasSemana   = 1;//configFechaInicioAnual.getInt(pClaveCalendario);

        return dc;
    }

    public class DatosCalendario{
        public String descripcion;
        public String inicio;
        public String fin;
        public Integer diasSemana;

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return " DatosCalendario [ descripcion=" + descripcion + ", inicio=" + inicio + ", fin=" + fin + ", diasSemana=" + diasSemana + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

And this is the exception thrown when getting 'SV2' with 'fechainicial':

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'null WHERE key ='SV2'' at line 1
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:686) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:663) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:653) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:115) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2041) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1827) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1930) ~[mysql-connector-java-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
>       at org.apache.commons.configuration2.DatabaseConfiguration$JdbcOperation.openResultSet(DatabaseConfiguration.java:847) ~[commons-configuration2-2.1.jar:2.1]
>       at org.apache.commons.configuration2.DatabaseConfiguration$1.performOperation(DatabaseConfiguration.java:333) ~[commons-configuration2-2.1.jar:2.1]
>       at org.apache.commons.configuration2.DatabaseConfiguration$JdbcOperation.execute(DatabaseConfiguration.java:742) [commons-configuration2-2.1.jar:2.1]
>       at org.apache.commons.configuration2.DatabaseConfiguration.getPropertyInternal(DatabaseConfiguration.java:359) [commons-configuration2-2.1.jar:2.1]
>       at org.apache.commons.configuration2.AbstractConfiguration.getProperty(AbstractConfiguration.java:992) [commons-configuration2-2.1.jar:2.1]
>       at org.apache.commons.configuration2.AbstractConfiguration.getAndConvertProperty(AbstractConfiguration.java:1749) [commons-configuration2-2.1.jar:2.1]
>       at org.apache.commons.configuration2.AbstractConfiguration.convert(AbstractConfiguration.java:1785) [commons-configuration2-2.1.jar:2.1]
>       at org.apache.commons.configuration2.AbstractConfiguration.getString(AbstractConfiguration.java:1344) [commons-configuration2-2.1.jar:2.1]
>       at com.ingartek.gtfs.bizkaibus.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration.getInfoCalendario(PropertiesConfiguration.java:83) [classes/:?]
>       at com.ingartek.gtfs.bizkaibus.main.GenerarGtfs.main(GenerarGtfs.java:43) [classes/:?]
>   13:55:15.120 [main] DEBUG com.ingartek.gtfs.bizkaibus.main.GenerarGtfs -  DatosCalendario [ descripcion=Sabados verano Julio Agosto, inicio=null, fin=, diasSemana=1]

What am I doing wrong? Could somebody provide an additional tutorial or documentation?

**SOLUTION**

As @Thilo told me, the solution was to use a table name without containing a "hyphen" ("-"). Unfortunately, it's working only in PostgreSQL and in MySQL I'm getting an exception:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key ='SV2' AND name='fechainicial'' at line 1

Comment: Try using a table name without a hyphen in it.

Comment: I'll try it now

Comment: Yeah! It worked, Also using postgresql. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same problem while using mysql

After few ours debug, i solved it by rename the **KeyColumn** name from 'key' to 'code'. You may use some other column name but not 'key'

Comment: Thanks for posting it!